# Google Charts: Pie chart not calculating percentages correctly?

Tags: bash, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am using the following code for a "Google Chart". This is for the pie-chart.

```
#! /bin/bash

export DISPLAY=":11.0"

## Define variables 


pname1=$(awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}' /home/gdata)
active1=$(awk 'NR == 1 {print $2}' /home/gdata)
total1=$(awk 'NR == 1 {print $3}' /home/gdata)
percent1=$(awk 'NR == 1 {print $4}' /home/gdata)

TEMP=$(mktemp -t chart.XXXXX)
cat > $TEMP <<EOF

<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Title');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows([
      ['Active', $active1],
      ['Total', $total1]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'$pname1 $percent1',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<table class="columns">
 <tr>
<td><div id="chart_div1" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
 </body> 
</html>
EOF

# open browser
case $(uname) in
Darwin)
  open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app $TEMP
  ;;

Linux|SunOS)
  firefox $TEMP
  ;;
esac
```

What is happening is my variables, $active and $total, do not match the $percent variable when the chart is rendered. For instance, in this chart the "total" represents 483 and the "active" represents 85. 85 is 17.6% of 483. On the pie chart, 85 shows as 15%.

[image]

[image]

Is there no way to make the chart try to make up the percentage as a total of 483, instead of 100?

Comment: Added a couple lines that are in the script above the html tag, This may be what your talking about.

Comment: Also I have seen and tried the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782773/google-pie-chart-percentage-calculation?rq=1 - But I have had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Data doesn't work like that. Total is total, you can't have a pie slice representing Total unless it's the only value. In which case you would just have a solid circle. What you can do is compare Active to Inactive. To get your inactive number just subtract Active from Total.

```
data.addRows([
  ['Active', $active1],
  ['Inactive', $total1 - $active1]
]);
```

Comment: Well that makes my "active" count show the expected percentage (17.6%) in the tool tip. But this has the unwanted side effect of decreasing the actual total, which now shows 398 and 82.4%. I don't suppose there is a way to manipulate this number as well is there as to have it show 483?

Comment: You can't show total as a slice on a pie chart. It's a logical error. Are you trying to display total somewhere else?

Comment: No, I want it in the tool tip. There is a workaround in that I could use the "tooltip.text" parameter and set it to only show the value, however there seems to be a bug with pie charts from what I am reading and it seems to get ignored in the code. So at this point I suppose I am stuck. Thanks for the help.